# About the dimension of the longitudinal component of vector field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, renormalization, vector-fields

According to this lecture note http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~wit00103/qft05.pdf

page 115. Consider a Lagrangian for a massive vector field

> $$L = -\frac{1}{4} (\partial_{\mu} V_{\nu}  - \partial_{\nu} V_{\mu}  )^2 - \frac{1}{2} M^2 V_{\mu}^2 + ie V_{\mu} \bar{\psi} \gamma^{\mu} \psi  - \bar{\psi} (\partial \!\!\!/ +m)\psi    $$

It is said

> Note that the dimension of the vector ﬁeld is generically equal to 1, but since the longitudinal
>   component carries no derivatives in $L$, its dimension is equal to 2.

I could not get why the dimension of the longitudinal component is 2. How to see that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the longitudinal components are derivatives of scalars, $\partial_\mu\phi$. For a massive spin-1 $V_\mu$ they appear only in the mass term $M^2_V V_\mu^2$. That is where the dimension $2$ comes from.

Comment: There are only spinor $\psi$ and vector $V_{\mu}$ fields in the action, where does scalar $\phi$ comes from?

Comment: How as I have written: the longitudinal component of a massive vector is actually a scalar. That is what 'longitudinal' means: it is the gradient part i.e. $\partial\phi$. Being more specific, any vector field can be decomposed into a transverse part, two degrees of freedom, and one longitudinal part i.e. one degree of freedom proportional to the momentum. The transverse part only makes for a massless vector whereas the extra degree of freedom is needed to get a massive boson with its 3 polarizations. Another way to see it is via the Higgs mechanism.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean by http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition#Longitudinal_and_transverse_fields $V_{\mu}=-\nabla \phi + ...$ the $\nabla \phi$ is the traverse part. But, how do you know the dimension of the scalar field is 1 here? From $M^2 V_{\mu}^2 $ term, I would expect the dimension of $V_{\mu} \sim \nabla \phi$ is $M^1$.

Comment: @user26143: $\nabla\phi$ is the longitudinal part, not the transverse one. The (scaling) dimension of a field is set by its kinetic energy. Let me focus on the longitudinal part, that is I take $V_\mu=\partial_\mu\phi/M_V$ and set to zero the transverse for simplicity.

Comment: The $\partial_\mu V_\mu-\partial_\nu A_\mu$ clearly vanishes on the longitudinal component (indeed that kinetic term is nothing but the 2-form $dA$). On the other hand, the mass term $\frac{1}{2} M_V^2 V_\mu^2=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu\phi)^2$. From this expression you clearly see that $\phi$ has scaling dimension $1$ and hence $\partial_\mu\phi/M_V$ has scaling dimension $2$.

Comment: Sorry I messed up transverse and longitudinal. $\phi \sim M^1$, $\partial_{\mu} \phi \sim M^2$, $V_{\mu}=\partial_{\mu} \phi / M_V \sim M^1$. And the interaction part $V_{\mu} \bar{\psi} \gamma^{\mu} \psi$ has dimension 4, not 5 as the lecture note indicated, if I was not miscounting..

Comment: @user26143: you are indeed miscounting :-) The point is that while $\partial\phi$ has scaling dimension 2, also $\partial\phi/M_V$ has scaling dimension 2. Your confusing the scaling dimension with the so-called engineering dimension. $M_V$ is just a parameter and it doesn't scale, it is what it is. This means that $V_\mu\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu \psi$ contains a non-renormalizable term from the longitudinal part, $\frac{1}{M_V}\partial_\mu\phi \bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu \psi $, where the ``cutoff'' $\Lambda$ is $M_V$ itself. Beside, if you found my answer useful you are kindly invited to upvote it :-)

Comment: Sorry, I still do not get the point :( Consider a real scalar theory, the kinetic term is $\partial_{\mu} \phi \partial^{\mu} \phi$, we infer from the dimension of Lagrangian that $\phi \sim M^1$. The mass in the mass term $m^2 \phi^2$ has to be taken as $M^1$ to match the dimension of Lagrangian $M^4$. Similarly, why the $M_V$ in $M_V^2 V_{\mu}^2$ term (assuming your $M_V$ is the same as $M$ in the lecture note) does not taken into account?

Comment: @user26143: all terms in the lagrangian must have the same mass dimension, it wouldn't even make any sense otherwise (it would be like summing apples and oranges...). Instead, for the scaling property of the various operators in the lagrangian (as if you want to understand whether it is renormalizable or not), you should treat all the couplings and masses as mere parameters that do not scale. As I have written above, the coupling to the longitudinal components $\frac{1}{M_V}\partial_\mu\phi \bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi$, tells you that the Lagrangian is not renomalizable just as it is.